# Troubles with Nvidia card and Linux

Tags: linux, freeze, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

I own a laptop whose specs are i7-7700hq and Nvidia Geforce 750m.
It came with preinstalled Windows 10, so I went for a dual boot setup with Linux. I've tried Ubuntu and Debian (both 8 and 9), but every time something goes wrong in the installation and it apparently fails to properly support my graphic card.
Trying over and over, I stumbled upon many different errors and warnings, the most relevant were:

- "nouveau Pointer to TMDS table invalid" when booting, then it freezes.
- Everything freezes just after user login.
- Wall of PCI error messages after booting.

Googling, I found that a possible workaround could be booting with the GRUB option "nomodeset", which actually worked sometimes. Specifically, in Ubuntu it works but graphics is ugly and outrageously slow, unusable.
In Debian 9 it's better, the system works decently but has flaws: first of all, I can't change the brightness of the screen in any way (/etc/class/backlight folder is empty), also I'm pretty sure that the system is running with the Intel HD videocard instead of my Nvidia. 
If it can help, this is the output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 05)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 05)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 591b (rev 04)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 05)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 31)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation CM238 HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 950M] (rev a2)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter (rev ff)
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
```

I'm sure I have to manually install drivers or something, but I'm not sure where to start. Currently I have Debian 9 with nomodeset, if I remove it I get the login freeze error.
Of course I can provide more details if asked.

Do you have any tip or solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You aren't grasping the purpose of `nomodeset` which is a temporary workaround until you install the Nvidia proprietary drivers. Of course it will give low graphics, low performance, that's the whole point, not loading drivers that may not support the graphics correctly. In Ubuntu you can open Additional Drivers and just select and apply the recommended version (internet required). In Debian, first find out which version to install then `sudo apt-get install nvidia-XXX` (where XXX is the driver version number).

Comment: @MichaelBay if this were an answer I'd upvote it.    You can also generaly go to Nvidias website and download a binary package you can run which  will give you the latest drivers.